# Application update server

Tags: c++, qt, client

my application (QT, MSVC2010) requires constant updates both in code (the executable file itself) and data (files to be used by the customer).
The main issue is that not every user has the right to download the whole set of updates so I need a way to send him only the appropiate files.
I decided to do something like this:

- Client: send user ID
- Server: check user ID in database, send him
  appropiate updates
- Client: receive updates

At this stage I'm not focusing on security issues (authentication, encryption), I'd just like to know if there is any ready solution I could use or if I have to code this by myself. Even a partial solution would be of great help.
I'm not aware of any server side application that can handle this kind of situation but I must admit this is really not my field.

Last point: I need to avoid any web based solution (user logging in a website, PHP and so on) for a very long list of reasons.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's really an answer, I can just describe how I've implemented very similar design in a simple way some time ago.

1) Client has a version information build in (through .rc file) and user credentials
2) Client access central database checking if there is a URL for it's current version and user credentials.

```
 select url from some table for credentials and version more then current version
```

3) Client fetches updates as single zip file using Url from Http/Ftp using standard Qt classes. If you need custom made protocol you might want to implement some logic over it.
4) Client update itself based on received data
5) Client notifies server about update complete so we know whats installed where

It's really very simple skeleton with a lot of limitations, but it's solved perfect everything I needed in that project. So you can deploy an update for particular user without affecting others.

Comment: Hey Evilruff, I apologize for the veeeery late feedback, I never got any notification or update of your answer. At the end I implemented pretty much the same solution. It has limitations, true, but not in my case (our case?). Thank you a lot, 7 years later :)